# Is it possible to force Eclipse to preserve accurate line numbers for compiled java classes?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, compilation

Most of the compiled classes in my eclipse project have line numbers and pseudo-line numbers that look like this:

[image]

In the case above, if I want to set a breakpoint at the literal line number 691 (which is `String METHODNAME = "executeAction";`, then I have to actually set the breakpoint at line 599 way up in the file.  If that line is blank, it's actually impossible to set a breakpoint on this this line.

This makes debugging issues quite a headache, and sometimes downright impossible if they line up in an unfortunate way.  I really don't understand why this happens, but I'm assuming it's trying to enhance speed at the cost of being easily debuggable, and eclipse is doing it's best to reverse engineer the compilation.  Or something to that affect.

Is there some way I can recompile all of these classes while forcing Eclipse to preserve the original line numbers so that I can effectively debug issues in my local environment?

Comment: Eclipse *already* preserves the line numbers accurately. Your sources must not match the information in your class files.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the real question is: This is decompiled source code, and you wonder if you can teach Eclipse to match the line lumbers of the decompiled source to the locations in the .class file?

Then the answer is no. Best thing you can do in the example is to set a method entry breakpoint instead, which is independent of the line number (but note that due to jvm restrictions, this kind of break point can make execution slower)

If the code in question is opensource, you should try to download the matching  source version. Otherwise can you try to edit the decompiled code so the actual line numbers match the original line numbers as good as possible.